# Display Specific Data Based on ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The following code displays a list of markers from my data API, on marker click it sets selectedMarker state with the ID of the marker the user clicked.

```
getPosts() {
    axios
      .get("mydataAPI")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          posts: response.data.response
        });
      });
  }

///This code is then returned to the user with MapView to display a list of markers on map, when a user clicks a marker the ID of that marker is stored in state ///

 {this.state.posts.map((user, index)=> {
       return (
        <MapView.Marker key={user.ID} coordinate={{latitude: user.lat, longitude: user.lng}} onPress={() => {this.setState({selectedMarker: user.ID})}}  title={user.category} description={Moment(user.post_date).fromNow(), user.category, user.address} image={require('../images/yes.png')}/>
          );
                 })}

//// will display ID of marker user selected ////

{ this.state.selectedMarker }
```

Now that I have the marker ID saved as a state how can I use the .map function to display information about that specific marker based on its ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash npm package.

Add a function on `<MapView onPress={() => {showUserDetails(user.ID)} />`

```
import {
    findIndex
} from 'lodash';

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    Index: -1
  }
}

showUserDetails = (id) => {
let Index = findIndex(this.state.posts, {
        'ID': id
    });
this.setState({Index});
}
```

Then in render method :

```
{this.state.Index !== -1 ? (
   <Text>this.state.posts[this.state.Index].ID</Text>
   <Text>this.state.posts[this.state.Index].lat</Text>
   <Text>this.state.posts[this.state.Index].lng</Text>
) : null}
```

If it don't work then let me know the data inside this.state.posts.